# Custom file type is not showing "Open With"

Tags: swift, uti, transferable, document-types

I might be going insane, I followed so many tutorials and still my custom file type is not able to be opened within my app -

[image: Here is my info setup for the custom file type]

Here is my custom `UTType` extension:

```
extension UTType {
    static let reminderList: UTType = UTType(exportedAs: "com.brettrosen.Mocha.reminder-list")
}
```

As well as my `Transferable` conformance:

```
static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
    CodableRepresentation(contentType: .reminderList)
}
```

I'm at a loss for why I can share this as this custom file type but there is no option to open with it. I see the data is in json format in exactly how I'd expect it, so I have no idea what I'm missing. Really hoping someone can spot it

Comment: The option to open the custom file type with your app will appear in other apps when they choose to share an instance of your custom file. A good test is to save a file of your custom type to the Files app. Then run the Files app and go to that file and then choose to share it. Your app should then appear as one of the options.

Comment: @HangarRash I was under the impression if I used the share link to send this file through iMessage, I would be able to open it in my app. Maybe I'm not looking for the right solution here?